# How to modify response head in HTTP to get JavaScript file response?

Tags: http, cache-control

I found some answer about HTTP cache, but one question still remains:
I can set the response header to take notice of the js file cache,
but the HTTP for the js file is sent as auto response by the browser.

How can I capture and modify the response?